# serialize and deserializing objects with no-args constructor problem

Tags: java, android-studio, serialization

I'm using [ECIES](https://www.flexiprovider.de/examples/ExampleECIES.html) in my code for encryption. The example in the provided website works without problem. I need a way to convert the keys (public and private keys) to string, serialize and deserialize them, using any tools. However, after trying gson and a few other techniques, yet I cannot serialize and deserialize the keys. Since there are many objects of 3-rd party classes, it is not easy to change the classes.

The code:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;

import de.flexiprovider.common.exceptions.ECException;
import de.flexiprovider.common.ies.IESParameterSpec;
import de.flexiprovider.core.FlexiCoreProvider;
import de.flexiprovider.ec.FlexiECProvider;
import de.flexiprovider.ec.parameters.CurveParams;
import de.flexiprovider.ec.parameters.CurveRegistry.BrainpoolP160r1;

import static java.security.Security.addProvider;

public class ExampleECIES {
static Context context;
ExampleECIES(Context ctx){
    context=ctx;
}
private ExampleECIES() {
}
static {
    // register the FlexiECProvider
    addProvider(new FlexiECProvider());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    addProvider(new FlexiCoreProvider());
    addProvider(new FlexiECProvider());

    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECIES", "FlexiEC");

    CurveParams ecParams = new BrainpoolP160r1();

    kpg.initialize(ecParams, new SecureRandom());
    KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
    PublicKey pubKey = keyPair.getPublic();
    PrivateKey privKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String pubKeystr = gson.toJson(pubKey),privKeystr=gson.toJson(privKey);
    Log.e("pubkey->String(Gson)",pubKeystr);
    PublicKey pubKey2 = gson.fromJson(pubKeystr, PublicKey.class);




    // Encrypt

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES", "FlexiEC");

    IESParameterSpec iesParams = new IESParameterSpec("AES128_CBC",
            "HmacSHA1", null, null);

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey, iesParams);
    String cleartextFile = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/"+"ECIES-cleartext.txt";
    String ciphertextFile = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/"+"ECIES-ciphertextECIES.txt";



    byte[] block = new byte[64];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cleartextFile);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ciphertextFile);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
    int i;
    while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) {
        cos.write(block, 0, i);
    }
    cos.close();
    // fis.close();

    File testFile1 = new File(cleartextFile);
    Log.e("Location:",cleartextFile);
    Log.e("size of msg:",String.valueOf(testFile1.length()));

    File testFile2 = new File(ciphertextFile);
    Log.e("Location:",ciphertextFile);
    Log.e("size of cipher:",String.valueOf(testFile2.length()));

    // Decrypt




    String cleartextAgainFile = context.getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/"+"ECIES-cleartextAgainECIES.txt";

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey, iesParams);
    fis = new FileInputStream(ciphertextFile);

    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
    fos = new FileOutputStream(cleartextAgainFile);
    byte[] block1 = new byte[64];
    int length=0;
      while ((i= cis.read(block1)) != -1) {
         fos.write(block1, 0, i);
         length+=1;
     }
    fos.close();
}

}
```

The log:

```
E/value: Permission Granted, Now you can use local drive .
I/Choreographer: Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/pubkey->String(Gson): {"mParams":{"E":{"mA":{"mP":    {"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152}},"mB":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088}},"mQ":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"g":{"mA":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152}},"mB":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088}},"mX":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":1089473557631435284577962539738532515920566082499}},"mY":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":127912481829969033206777085249718746721365418785}},"mZ":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":1}},"mE":{"mA":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152}},"mB":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088}},"mQ":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"k":1,"oid":{"value_":[1,3,36,3,3,2,8,1,1,1],"explicit_":true,"optional_":false},"q":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"r":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085038830181364212942568457}},"mW":{"mA":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152}},"mB":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088}},"mX":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":628394263989319164273890624957594403688612269204}},"mY":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":1072026760431506144307858012106945103504499745844}},"mZ":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":1}},"mE":{"mA":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152}},"mB":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088}},"mQ":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}}}
E/onClick12: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface java.security.PublicKey. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
E/value: Permission Granted, Now you can use local drive .
```

Since I recently started using Java, I appreciate a clear and understandable solution.

**EDIT:**
I fix the code by replacing the instance of the class with the its implementation as below:

```
    ...
    Log.e("PublicKey class", String.valueOf(pubKey.getClass()));
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String pubKeystr = gson.toJson(pubKey),privKeystr=gson.toJson(privKey);
    Log.e("pubkey->String(Gson)",pubKeystr);
    PublicKey pubKey2 = gson.fromJson(pubKeystr, de.flexiprovider.ec.keys.ECPublicKey.class);
    ...
```

The result:

```
E/PublicKey class: class de.flexiprovider.ec.keys.ECPublicKey
E/pubkey->String(Gson): {"mParams":{"E":{"mA":{"mP": 
{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue": {"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152}},"mB":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088}},"mQ":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"g":{"mA":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152}},"mB":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088}},"mX":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":1089473557631435284577962539738532515920566082499}},"mY":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue": {"bigInt":127912481829969033206777085249718746721365418785}},"mZ":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue": {"bigInt":1}},"mE":{"mA":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152}},"mB":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088}},"mQ":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"k":1,"oid":{"value_":[1,3,36,3,3,2,8,1,1,1],"explicit_":true,"optional_":false},"q":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"r":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085038830181364212942568457}},"mW":{"mA":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152}},"mB":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088}},"mX":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":732184415350565563503541898303690594141588218210}},"mY":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":1069191161364546078005104901313515997036014364970}},"mZ":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue": {"bigInt":1}},"mE":{"mA":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":297190522446607939568481567949428902921613329152}},"mB":{"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159},"mValue":{"bigInt":173245649450172891208247283053495198538671808088}},"mQ":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}},"mP":{"bigInt":1332297598440044874827085558802491743757193798159}}}
E/onClick12: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class 
de.flexiprovider.ec.parameters.CurveParams. Register an InstanceCreator with 
Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be from this line:

```
PublicKey pubKey2 = gson.fromJson(pubKeystr, PublicKey.class);
```

A PublicKey is an interface in Java - means it declares a set of methods that concrete objects implement to adhere to that interface.  In particular, you cannot instantiate (create) an instance of an interface; rather you need to specify a concrete implementation.  So... either:

```
PublicKey pubKey2 = gson.fromJson(pubKeystr, YourConcretePublicKeyImplementation.class);
```

OR, you configure gson to tell it to construct instances of "YourConcretePublicKeyImplementation.class" when it is told to deserialize the PublicKey interface.

Of course "YourConcretePublicKeyImplementation.class" is just a placeholder here - you need to use the (correct) concrete implementation.  For that you'd need to know what implementation of PublicKey was serialized in the first place.

To do that, simply log (or print) the full class name of the pubKey variable you create earlier in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the point and your explanation, very useful for me. I changed the code to replace the instance with its implementation. However, the error is still there. I edited the question to include the new error.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a better look into the public key class, I realized that the class itself provides a .getstring() to serialize the public key. Afterwards, I used the following code to convert the string to public key again:

```
   ...
   byte[] publicBytes =pubKey.getEncoded();
   X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicBytes);
   KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECIES", "FlexiEC");
   PublicKey pubKey2 = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
   ...
```

Comment: Yes.  Wiser to use the built-in functionality to persist and re-instantiate things like public/private keys.